# WinAppDriver: Launching of desktop application was working fine, but of late its having issues

Tags: c#, winappdriver

Launching of the desktop application was working fine when I automated using `winAppDriver`.
Of late I observed these tests are failing.

Its failing at this line,

> notepadsession = new WindowsDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), desiredcapabilities);

I tried both the codes, but still failing:

```
     var currentWindowHandle = notepadsession.CurrentWindowHandle;
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        var allWindowHandles = notepadsession.WindowHandles;
        notepadsession.SwitchTo().Window(allWindowHandles[0]);



    if (notepadsession.CurrentWindowHandle != notepadsession.WindowHandles.Last())
        {
            notepadsession.SwitchTo().Window(notepadsession.WindowHandles.Last());
        }
```

NOTE: It takes around 40-50 seconds to load the Desktop application.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved the problem

```
notepadsession = new WindowsDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), desiredcapabilities);

Thread.Sleep(5000);    
notepadsession.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ms:waitForAppLaunch` capability enables WinAppDriver to wait for a defined amount of time after an app launch is initiated prior to attaching to the application session. The limit for this is 50 seconds.

C#: `appCapabilities.SetCapability("ms:waitForAppLaunch", "25");` to add app delay of 25 seconds.

For more information check out the [release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/releases/tag/v1.2-RC).